# git pull from one server, merges and push to 2nd server

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, gitlab

I have a git repo on bit-bucket with master branch only where some developers works.

Now I want to host this repo on my own gitlab server with update master branch from bitbucket and two more branch dev and stag that created and manage by my own.

[image]

Now what I wanted.

- Step 1 : pull **`master`** branch from **git cloud** on my local machine,
- Step 2 : create new branch from **`master`** names **`dev`** and **`stag`** and push to **git server**.
- Step 3 : I work on `**dev**` and `**stag**` branch only and push changes to with respective branches on **git server.**
- Step 4 : some developers push code on git cloud `**master**` branch, then I pull master branch, merge changes with `**dev**` and `**stag**` branch, then push all of 3 to git server.

I want the master branch to stay up-to-date with git cloud. and dev and staging also contains update-to-date code of master branch including mine work that i done on `dev` and `stag`. What flow can i do this?

> Note: I don't want any automatic process /hooks.

Comment: I pull from git cloud with `master` with remote origin branch and then add a new remote dest with master branch push to git server, there I create 2 more branches `dev` and `master`.

Comment: And what does not work like expected, what is your problem?

Comment: @Vampire i crated both branches on gitlab. Now on my local machine, I `git remote -v` have 2 `origin` and `dest`. Then I want to fetch dev and stag branch on local machine, I tried `git fetch dest && git checkout dest stag`

```
 * [new branch]      dev        -> dest/dev
 * [new branch]      stag       -> dest/stag
error: pathspec 'dest' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'stag' did not match any file(s) known to git
```
Then i run : `git branch` then i only have `master` branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your local machine, you can try steps as below:

**1.    Migrate from git cloud (repo on bitbucket) to git server (repo on gitlab).**

```
git clone <URL for git cloud>
git remote add dest <URL for git server>
git checkout -b dev
git checkout -b stag
git push dest --all
```

**2. Sync changes from git cloud master branch to git server repo.**

When the master branch on git cloud is updated, in the local repo, you can use below steps:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout dev
git pull origin master --rebase
git checkout stag
git pull origin master --rebase
```

Now all the three branches are contain the update master branch  from git cloud.

Comment: Your solutions works, But when i list branches using `git branch -a` it shows this
  `dev`,
  `master`,
  `* stag`,
  `remotes/dest/dev`,
  `remotes/dest/master`,
  `remotes/dest/stag`,
  `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`,
  `remotes/origin/dev` and 
  `remotes/origin/master`
 
 Why origin has dev too?

Comment: `dev, master, stag` means the local branches. `remotes/dest/dev, remotes/dest/master, remotes/dest/stag` means branches in your remote dest(gitlab). `remotes/origin/dev and remotes/origin/master` means branches in your remote origin(git cloud). `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` means your current branch is master. `git branch -a` list all the branches in local and remotes.

Comment: ok, I got it there was also a dev branch on git cloud, I didnt' check that. Initially I thought there is only master branch on gitcloud.

Comment: because git cloud remote is origin, when you use `git push`, git will push to origin by default. You can use `git push origin :dev` to delete dev branch on git cloud.

Answer (score 0):

With `git checkout dest stag` `dest` and `stag` are interpreted as paths to update from the index, but you don't have those paths in your repository. What you want to do is `git checkout stag` or `git checkout -b stag dest/stag` or `git branch stag dest/stag`.